# Global function issue

Tags: python, visual-studio, error-handling, global

Global function not working !

This is my code:

```
import time 


print('hello again islam '.title())

time.sleep(2)

def question():
    global action
    action = input('how do you feel today ? : '.title())
    x = 2

if action == 'good':
    print('good !'.upper())

elif action == 'not good':
    print('letsplay'.upper())

else:
    question()
```

The output:

> name 'action' is not defined

Comment: what is `globals()['action']` ? KeyError ?

Comment: Perhaps ```action``` is used some where else but the definition was inside the function

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: Call the question function once before the if condition.

This is the order of execution after `time.sleep()` is called:

1. Function `question()` is defined but it is not run.
2. Value of `action` is checked against `'good'`.

   -->this is where error occur because question is not called till now so action is not assigned a value.

Call the `question()` function once before the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Add some initial value to global variable as empty string then get from input.